# Record UI elements for TestFX

Tags: automated-testing, java, windows, desktop-application, application-software-testing

There is an existing `JavaFX` based application, which I should write automated tests for. I just started to use `TestFX`(version 4.0.13-alpha) and looking for advice, how to record and identify UI objects of application. I tried following code to initialize a button, but it couldn't be clicked.

```
Button button = new Button("submit");
```

I found [these](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool) GUI inspect tools, but not sure, which one could works with TestFX.

Comment: Could you add your TestFX test code, especially the lookup?

Comment: @beatngu13 : I need to write black box tests, so it doesn't exists yet.